# Put ads in windows 8.1 app

Tags: windows-8.1, ads

I want to show ads in my app.For this I use Microsoft Advertising sdk to get started. I have shown the ads but when I set the payment methods in pubCenter my country is not in the list . Is there any other 3rd party ads unit for 8.1 app ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this link alternatives for pubCenter

http://superdevresources.com/pubcenter-alternatives-windows-phone/

Answer (score 1):

Leadbolt currently supports Windows Tablet 8.0 and 8.1 with an ad-serving SDK including the bundled cross promotion ads and analytics tools.

HTML based ad tags including house ads are currently available for the Windows Phone platform.

Answer (score 0):

As I have seen only leadboat has windows 8.1 support, and it says it is going to Depreacated. What a bad thing to be Windows 8.1 DEV in a country which microsoft pubcenter do not support

https://www.leadbolt.net/

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Microsoft advertising SDK for over a year, but recently I found a new ad network that works on Windows desktop app ads too. Then I integrated their SDK, it runs well in my apps, I earned much more than I did on Microsoft advertising. They support a variety of payment methods to different countries around the world. You can have a try, maybe they will support your country.

desktopad.com